# Php communication with java servlet parameters initialized to null

Tags: php, servlets, apache2

I am working on an existing project , which has a php file. The php sets a few params. These params , on hitting the servlet are shown as null.. when we do a request.getparam(). 
I am not sure why this happens on my apache2 - and php5.

How do I go about resolving this. I have put var_dump($variable) to get the output of the params being passed.. but i am not sure how i can resolve this issue. Have been trying to resolve it since a whole day now!

Please help!!

Comment: please add example code

Answer (score 0):

The php should not bother you. All you need to worry is the URL you are generating and how you get the parameters passed inside the servlet code. The URL generated by the php should be something like this: `http://host.com/AppName/ServletName?param1=xxx&param2=yyy&param3=zzz`

Now, there are two types you can call the servlet. With GET or POST. If you are just invoking the URL by a click event then the GET `doGet()` method in sevlet will be triggered. If you call the servlet using a form or ajax using POST, then the `doPost()` will be triggered inside the servlet.

Then inside the appropriate method you can get the parameters simply like this:

```
String parameter1 = request.getParameter("param1");
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. the php engine needed some other packages like curl , which lead to those errors. So , i basicaly ended up invoking the servlet directly rather than calling in from php code.